# Trying to display circle and text by nesting in g element, failing. what is wrong?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, append

I want to display one `<circle>` and `<text>` for each node. My code looks like this, having added the suggested code from the answer below. Please note the different

```
var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var nodes = [], 
    links = [];

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .charge(-250)
    .linkDistance(25)
    .size([width, height])
    .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(force.nodes(), function(d) { return d.id;}),
    link = svg.selectAll(".link");

var text=svg.selectAll("text") //simply add text to svg
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter()
    .append("text")
       .attr("class", "nodeText")
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
            .attr("font-size", "10px")
            .attr("fill", "red");

function start() {
    link = link.data(force.links(), function(d) { return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id; });
    link.enter().insert("line", ".node")
        .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.edgeType; })
        .attr("id", function(d) { return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id; });
    link.exit().remove();
```

v1: `<line>`s exist and are displayed, no `<circle>`s or `<text>` exist

```
    var g = node.enter().append("g");
    g.append("circle")
        .attr("class", function(d) { return "node " + d.id; })
        .attr("id", function(d) { return d.id; })
        .attr("r", 8)
    .on("click", nodeClick);
    g.append("text")
        .text(function(d) {return d.id; });
```

/v1
v2: `<line>`s and `<circle>`s exist and are displayed. `<text>`s exist within `<circle>`s but aren't displayed

```
    node = node.data(force.nodes(), function(d) { return d.id;});
    node.enter()
        .append("circle")
            .attr("class", function(d) { return "node " + d.id; })
            .attr("id", function(d) { return d.id; })
            .attr("r", 8)
        .on("click", nodeClick);
        node.append("text")
            .text(function(d) {return d.id; });
```

/v2

```
    node.exit().remove();
    force.start();
}

function nodeClick() {
    var node_id = event.target.id;
    handleClick(node_id, "node");
}

function tick() {

    text.attr("dx", function(d) { return d.x+5; })
        .attr("dy", function(d) { return d.y+5; })
        .text(function(d){return d.id});

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add text element as following in your js

```
var text=svg.selectAll("text") //simply add text to svg
    .data(Your_nodes_array)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
       .attr("class", "nodeText")
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
            .attr("font-size", "10px")
            .attr("fill", "red");
```

And inside tick do this :

```
text.attr("dx", function(d) { return d.x+5;}) //to keep it away from node
  .attr("dy", function(d) { return d.y+5; })
  .text(function(d){return d.id});
```

This will solve circle and text problems as this time we are adding text directly now

Comment: That is helpful, as `<text>` elements are now coming to existence, within the `<circle>`s. However, they are still not being displayed. I updated the Q.